# Grails JAX-RS Calling a class in src/groovy giving error - Message: No signature of method: is applicable for argument types

Tags: grails, groovy, jax-rs

While developing the rest api using jaxrs plugin I need to create some common class which I have created in "src/groovy". Below is the class

```
class ValidateToken {
    String validate(String token){
        println(token)  
        return "test"
    }
    //...
```

In resource file(jaxrs) this is what I am doing

```
def instance=ValidateToken.validate("test")
```

This throws error on runtime

```
The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re- throwing to the HTTP container
Message: No signature of method: static com.dogmasystems.touroperatorportal.Vali
dateToken.validate() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: validate(java.lang.String), wait()
```

I am not able to understand why it happening? Though I am sending a string value but it is being sent as a List. Also if the method is copied to the same resource file then it works fine and treats the passed parameter as String.

Also please let me know where to keep common classes/code which will be used in different Jax-RS resources.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either use `new ValidateToken.validate(...` or make your `validate` method `static`.  this is actually what the error is stating:

> No signature of method: **static** ....ValidateToken.validate() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`